# Database design for setting team schedules

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, mysql-workbench, database-schema

i'm Designing a sports tournament hosting website, and i have a basic database design set up, here is how it looks.
(i'm even willing to have a bounty on this question)

[image]

1. 'Asuming' admin table is the center of the database, there are two different roles for the admin `superadmin` and `admin`
2. The `superadmin` creates the `tournaments`
3. `superadmin` adds `teams`
4. each team will have an `admin`
5. the `admin` then adds `players` to the specific teams that he's incharge of
6. `superadmin` then creates `schedules` for the teams

lets say there are 20 teams and 20 admins and 100 players in the tounament
what would be the database design for this and how would i optimize it for maximum flexibility, as i will state below, there will be future additions to these already present features. here is the basic work flow

[image]

### Some required features

1. Teams should be able to play in multiple tournaments at different schedules(schedules should not overlap)
2. players should be able to play in multiple tounaments with different/same teams but **never** on multiple teams belonging to the same tournament
3. Teams should be able to play in multiple tournaments

### The future additions

1. the teams will be divided into pools/groups
2. some teams will play against other teams **within** the group
3. some teams will play against other teams in **other** groups

### Summarizing the question

- what would be the database design for the required features that i
  mentioned
- how would i plan for and accomodate the future additions right now
- im looking for purely database design and best methodology

Comment: @Ghayel dude! settle for 50?

Comment: @Ghayel yea, 50 rep is doable. 250 is overkill, i probably could do it myself, but yea i'm willing to put out 50 reps if i can get some support on this

Comment: Ok do it yourself and I'll fully support you if you have any problem. I can do if 250

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97609/discussion-between-ghayel-and-deez-nutz).

Comment: start chat. we can discuss

Comment: I did your work now its up to you as how much rep you reward me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer. Let me know if you want any explanation:
[image]

Comment: thank you! i will look into this in a couple of hours and let you know, kind of busy with other work now :)

Comment: @deeznutz have you please checked it? I am waiting for your reply

Comment: waiting for your reply

Comment: Ah hey! was on an extended vacation, i'm back (with a killer sunburn tho), there are a couple of things that does't sit right here, 1). why is there a many to many between player and team, this is contrary to what i specified 2). the schedule table holds relationship between tournaments and teams, rather it should be between TWO teams, and also there is no relationship between tournament and team and, team and players. Reps is only something i have to think about if i get an awesome answer which changes the way i've designed my application.

Comment: 1) Player team contains many players data whereas a player can play in many teams and there may be many teams in a tournament thus this is obviously many to many relationship (2) I suppose there may be different tournaments and different teams are playing. Anyways let me know how you want it to change the design immediately

Comment: I am waiting for your reply

Comment: hey, that worked out well, at first i had a different design, then i changed it to someting similar to yours, so i will accept your answer, i like your hunger so i'm also gona give you a +1. thanks i learnt something new!

Comment: @deeznutz you promised for 50 bounties before I started work whereas I was demanding 250.

Comment: actually this turned out to be a much more complex design than originally thought, i had to make a lot of changes, and comparitively this is just a simple structure, so i thought 25 reps would be relevant, since you followed up with this every. single. day.

Comment: @Ghayel, how would you then use this info to create some statistics regarding results of each tournaments?